# Erro install ruby with rbenv ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, environment-variables, rbenv

I'm trying to set up my Ubuntu environment, and for that I need to install ruby ​​to start working, I have until Friday to get it :/

I'm using rbenv as instructed, I followed the step-by-step instructions, but it didn't work.

I try it:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

then

```
rbenv install rbx-5.0
```

But I get this error:

```
Downloading rubinius-5.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/c9e90e3ef2fb80714b09895611152024fecbb3f13955298fa63e57b1785e8ff0
Installing rubinius-5.0...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 21.04 using ruby-build 20210720-1-g37d7143)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20210722014142.33410.qcx0sZ
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20210722014142.33410.log

Last 10 log lines:
Via: 1.1 d5488e7054c0eb6827749a115e047e78.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: GRU1-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: HB0MkMd80NIfXeSNOw6h3BURsv4p3ZQfBu5c9nbc4yWKf4xTQ2_xSw==
Age: 1504

/tmp/ruby-build.20210722014142.33410.qcx0sZ/rubinius-5.0 /tmp/ruby-build.20210722014142.33410.qcx0sZ ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
find: ‘build/rubinius/codedb’: No such file or directory
find: ‘build/codetools/’: No such file or directory
find: ‘build/stdlib/’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: “ruby”: No such file or directory
```

Seems like everything has broken.

I already do it:
https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1067

look at my ~/.bashrc

```
...
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I also tried running this command before ruby-build: `source ~/.bashrc`

How can I solve it?

Comment: You say you need to install Ruby, but are actually attempting to install Rubinius (rbx), which is a separate, special and partly diverging implementation of the Ruby language. Unless you specifically need Rubinius, you should instead use MRI Ruby (i.e. "plain" Ruby). For most existing projects, there are version requirements for your Ruby version which is generally documented somewhere. The newest version of Ruby may not work with your project.

Comment: If you actually need Rubinius, please make sure to install another Ruby version first as Rubinius requires a working Ruby in order to build it. See https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/tree/v5.0#installing-rubinius